# Problem with Voyager admin panel routing and Vue js router in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, voyager

I`m developing locally SPA application using Vuejs V2 in Laravel V8 framework.
My routes/web.php file have this codes:

> ```
> Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
>     Voyager::routes();
> });
>
> //for disallow accessing route from anywhere alse than api 
> Route::get('/{any?}', function () {
>     return view('welcome');
> })->where('any', '^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.\,-]*');
>
> Auth::routes();
> ```

Here is my routes.js file inside resources/js folder

> ```
> import VueRouter from "vue-router";
>
> const routes = [
>     {
>         path: "*",
>         component: require("./components/PageNotFound").default,
>         name: "PageNotFound"
>     },
>     {
>         path: "/",
>         component: require("./components/Home").default,
>         name: "home"
>     },
>
>     // other routes
>
> ];
>
> const router = new VueRouter({
>     mode: "history",
>     linkActiveClass: "active",
>     routes
> });
>
> export default router;
> ```

My problem is that i cant access Voyager http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin route in browser and redirects me to home page!
My Voyager installed successfully and before installing that i was developing frontend features so i have a lot routes in my routes.js file.
My question is how i can except Voyager admin group route in web.php or any other solutions maybe?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by stopping serve then start that, worked for me and i can now see admin panel.